Local function app cannot connect to Azure SQL via managed id
I'm running a .NET 6.0 (tried upgrading to .NET 8.0 as well) function app locally. It's attempting to connect to Azure SQL, but I'm getting the following error

System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Tried to get token using Managed Identity. Access token could not be acquired. A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
(169.254.xxx.254:80)). Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Tried to get token using Managed Identity. Access token could not be acquired. A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.xxx:80).

Here's the connection string:
"Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx-001.database.windows.net;Database=xxxxxxxxxxxx-centralus-001;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;"

I have added my Microsoft Entra id to the database:

I'm able to use this username to connect to the database using SSMS, and I can select from it.
I ran this script to add a user to the database
create user [xxxxxx.com] for external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [xxxxxx.com];
alter role db_datawriter add member [xxxxxx.com];

What am I doing wrong? How do I get my local function app to connect and select from Azure SQL?
Don't know if it's helpful, but here's my .csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">                                                                 
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

i've also followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity tutorial.

Managed identity will work only when function app is running in Azure environments (the server for authentication of managed identity 169.254.xxx.254 is accessible only from Azure environment). When function app is running on local, you need to use different authentication like using service principal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-service-principal-authentication
or interactive authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-interactive-authentication
